# Убрать отступ в css-grid при маленьком расширении экрана

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

css-grid себя ведёт предсказуемо при среднем и большом расширении экрана. Однако, при создании мобильной версии сайта возникла проблема: появляется внешний отступ справа.

Контейнер вмещает в себе 7 блоков (шапка, подвал и т.д.).

```
.container {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 80px 500px 400px 400px 50px;
    grid-gap: 25px 25px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

И медиа-запрос для мобильной версии

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 300px 800px 400px 400px 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    grid-gap: 25px 0;
}
```

Почему, если одна колонка, то появляется этот отступ? Пробовал его убрать, изменяя свойство justify-content, но не получилось. Делал нулевые отступы, но безрезультатно. Пробовал компенсировать уменьшением размера контейнера до 85%, но результат меня не устроил, так как это не убирает сам отступ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина предельно проста и даже не имеет отношения к особенностям CSS-Grid. Дело в том, что в одном из грид-элементов был блок, ширина которого была больше своего контейнера (то есть самого грид-элемента). Собственно этот "аппендикс" и создавал внешний отступ справа от грид-элементов, выстроенных в колонку. Уменьшив ширину непослушного блока исчез и отступ.